# How to create usa today like News picture scroller?

Tags: android, scroll

How to create usa today like News picture scroller?

[image]

Comment: I really don't want to get the app to learn what it does. Can you explain better? From your image I imagine that it's a gallery that can be browsed sliding your finger.

Comment: yes, it is..any code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entire page scrolls, and not just the image, then if you put any longer than normal image in this will happen by default. I'm assuming since you nearly circled the entire thing the whole page scrolls, not just the image.